# How to find the object is UIImage or not?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in swift and i am implement one demo in which i have dictionary  with multiple object in which there are some UIImage objects.

How i  can differentiate UIImage object? I am using isKindClass but it is not work for me and give the error like "'AnyObject' dose not have member name isKindOfClass"

Code is like this

```
func initURLConnectionWithRequest(requestUrl:NSURL,apiTag:NSInteger,paramDic:NSDictionary,obj:NSObject) ->IMDRequest
    {
        var newRequest = IMDRequest()
        request1 = newRequest;
        self.tag=apiTag

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestUrl)
        var timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(60)
        request.timeoutInterval = timeInterval
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


        var strBoundry = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"

        var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(strBoundry)"

        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

        var bodyData = NSMutableData()

        var arrParamKey = paramDic.allKeys


        for var i = 0; i<arrParamKey.count; i++
        {
            if (paramDic.objectForKey(arrParamKey[i]).isKindOfClass(UIImage))
            {

            }
        }

        urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        self.senderObj = obj;
        urlConnection.start()
        self.isResponseReceived = false
        return request1;
    }
```

Comment: u get the extension of UIImage from server

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for comment but i mention in question that i have dictionary with object and i want to differentiate the object

Comment: what the result u get here paramDic.objectForKey(arrParamKey[i])

Comment: it is not fix may be UIImage or NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether the variable is of a type that you want, or that it conforms to some protocol, then you can use this as a reference:

```
var abc = …

if abc is <UIImage> {
    //the variable is of type <UIImage>
} else {
    //variable is not of type <UIImage>
}
```

This is same as isKindOfClass in Objective-C.

Hope this will help you.